# RSS Subscriber count without using FeedBurner

Tags: rss, subscription

I have a blog which is running on WordPress and I want to know how many users subscribe to my feeds. I know that if I used FeedBurner, I can get the counter from there. Is there any other way that I can track the subscribers easily?

Comment: Another GPL plugin is https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-feed-stats/ while https://wordpress.org/plugins/feedburner-alternative-and-rss-redirect/ introduces yet another external service to track visitors.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a wordpress question, but the [Feed Statistics plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-feed-statistics/) may do what you need.

Comment: It's free/libre software by the way, [GPL](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-feed-statistics/trunk/feed-statistics.php).